# How to rotate ellipse in PIL(Pillow)

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

So I want to add **rotated ellipse** (with some transparency) onto my image. How can I do this? I do this so:

```
def create_ellipse(fi):
    ellipse = Image.new('RGBA', (4*b, b*2), (255,255,255,0))
    draw_ellipse = ImageDraw.Draw(ellipse, "RGBA")
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im, 'RGBA')
    for l in range(b, -1, -1):
        colour = (red, green, blue, int(alpha/(b)))
        draw_ellipse.ellipse((b*2-l*2, b-l, b*2+l*2, b+l), fill=colour)
    rotated = ellipse.rotate(fi, expand=1, resample=Image.BICUBIC)
    im.paste(rotated, (x0-2*b, y0-b), rotated)
    return im
```

But my main picture has gray background so I have some problems with opacity.

Comment: There are a number of variables not defined in your sample code, which makes this harder to diagnose - b, red, green, blue, alpha, im, x0 and y0. fi would also be good. Using the following values, your code seems to work without a problem -

fi = 45,
b = 100,
red = 100,
green = 150,
blue = 200,
alpha = 10000,
im = Image.new('RGB', (500, 500), '#bbb'),
x0 = 50,
y0 = 50